# Dovecot - Prevent Downloading of "Old" Messages via POP3

Tags: dovecot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple messages in email clients](https://serverfault.com/questions/427046/multiple-messages-in-email-clients)

How can I set an option on Dovecot to stop delivery of old messages throught POP and deliver only messages from specific date or "from now on" to all my domains mail users in the server? I read that zimbra server has such option "download email from now on".

Comment: sorry for dublicate, in this post i tried to look at the problem from different point of view and try to explain why do I need this so badly. My boss is angry and I do not have much time.. Situation is very anoying...

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try before go back from server B to A (or A to B) delete all messages in the server  you are going to use? if you are using POP3 I bet you are downloading them too , not letting a copy at your server, then, after the failover you can "clean" the server you are gonna have as host for mails, and when your clients connect they wont anything new, so, no duplicate downloads will be.

You can use the plugin Expire for dovecot, I think could work for you.

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/Expire

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This dovecot plugin can do a trick.

Answer (score -1):

If you have mails in your mail server queue and if you don't want deliver them you can remove all queued mails by using this command(you not specified your server os)if you are using centos/redhat server

**postsuper -d ALL**

This command will clean all mails and after running this your server will start sending mails from now on.

Comment: Actually a problem is different. I have to MX servers(server1 - mx 10, server2 - mx 20) , and then I primary server back online after failure (hardware, internet, eletricity lost and etc) all desktop mail clients (MS Outlook 2000,2007,2010, Thunderbird, The Bat and etc) just redownload all mail through POP3. Inbox gets multiple copies off all email which are on the server. So MX failover is useless for me. How can I prevent them to redownload these messages then Server1 back online?

Comment: I have already tried to explain my situation in this post http://serverfault.com/questions/427046/multiple-messages-in-email-clients but no one answer me. I definetly need to find out workaround. Any help will be appriciated.